# Ensure express app is running before starting mocha tests

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, couchbase, supertest

I built an API for a couchbase database, using express and node.js. My problem is that when I run my tests some of them fail, because the server is not fully running. I found a solution here https://mrvautin.com/ensure-express-app-started-before-tests on how to solve this issue. The article stated that in order to solve this issue, you have to add an event emitter in your server file like this

```
app.listen(app_port, app_host, function () {
    console.log('App has started');
    app.emit("appStarted");
});
```

and then add this, in your test file

```
before(function (done) {
    app.on("appStarted", function(){
        done();
    });
});
```

I have tried this, here is my implementation

**Server File**

```
app.listen(config['server']['port'], function(){
    app.emit("appStarted");
    logger.info("Listening")
})
```

**Test File**

```
before(function(done){
    app.on("appStarted", function(){
        done();
    })
});
```

I keep on getting the following error

```
  1) "before all" hook in "{root}":
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

The article is from 2016, so I was thinking that maybe the syntax has been deprecated. I was wondering if someone could please help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the below condition, more info see ["Accessing the main module".](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module)

```
if (require.main === module) {
     // this module was run directly from the command line as in node xxx.js
} else {
     // this module was not run directly from the command line and probably loaded by something else
}
```

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

if (require.main === module) {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App has started');
  });
}

export { app, port };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { app, port } from './';
import http from 'http';
import request from 'supertest';

describe('63822664', () => {
  let server: http.Server;
  before((done) => {
    server = app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log('App has started');
      done();
    });
  });
  after((done) => {
    server.close(done);
    console.log('App has closed');
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    return request(server)
      .get('/')
      .expect(200);
  });
});
```

integration test result:

```sh
(node:22869) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
  63822664
App has started
    ✓ should pass
App has closed


  1 passing (26ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

!Hi World! My little solution here:

Check this: All depends of your testing markup...
For example, I'm using Mocha and Chai Assertion Library.

```js
const express = require('express');
const request = require("request");
const http    = require("http");
const expect  = require("chai").expect;
require('dotenv').config();

describe('Server', function() {
  const { PORT } = process.env;
  const app = express();
  before((done) => {
    http.Server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Listening Node.js server on port: ${PORT}`);
      done();
    });
  });
  it('should return 404 response code status', () => {
    const url = `http://localhost:${PORT}/api/v1/yourPath`;
    return request(url, (err, response, body) => {
      /* Note this result 'cause I don't have any get('/')
      controller o function to return another code status
      */
      expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(404);
    });
  })
});
```